# install kdevelop 4.7 plugin kdev-control-flow-graph

Tags: plugins, visualization, kdevelop4

os: centos 7; kdevelop 4.7.1;

I downloaded the source from https://github.com/KDE/kdev-control-flow-graph. It is a code visualization plugin for kdevelop 4: https://liveblue.wordpress.com/2009/06/17/visualize-your-code-in-kdevelop/.

After I built it with the following commands: "cmake .; make; make install; kbuildsycoca4;" , it doesn't show up in "loaded plugins".

> echo $KDEIDRS
>   /usr
>   I also tried "cmake . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr", but the result is the same. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed pre-built KDevelop 4.7.1 by yum.

I built "kdev-control-flow-graph" by reference: https://regx.dgswa.com/html/content/how-build-and-install-plugins-kdevelop. I also modified "CMakeLists.txt" by adding the following lines:

```
set(SERVICES_INSTALL_DIR /usr/share/kde4/services)
set(DATA_INSTALL_DIR /usr/share/kde4/apps)
set(PLUGIN_INSTALL_DIR /usr/lib/kde4)
```

but my centos 7 is a 64 bit system, the libs for kdevelop 4 lie in "/usr/lib64/kde4". After I changed this, everything is OK.

Find KDevelop 4 libary path by:

```
find /usr/ -type f -name "*kdev*.so*"
```

https://community.kde.org/KDevelop/HowToCompile_v4#2._Get_the_sources_.28assumes_.24HOME.2Fsrc_but_you_can_replace_it_with_something_else.29